# pygameがインストールできません

Tags: pygame

pygameがインストールできません。OSはWindows10です。コマンドプロンプトを立ち上げて、

C:\Windows\System32>cd C:\Users\〇〇〇\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311
と入力すると（〇〇〇は漢字実名.\は￥です）

C:\Users\〇〇〇\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311>

となるので、そこに「pip3 install pygame」と入力してEnterキーを押すと、

C:\Users\〇〇〇\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311>pip3 install pygame
Fatal error in launcher: Unable to create process using '"C:\Users????\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\python.exe"  "C:\WINDOWS\system32\pip3.exe" install pygame': ??????????????????

とエラーになります。〇〇〇のところが漢字で、それが原因かなとおもうのですが、それをアルファベットに変更する方法もわかりません（他の原因かもしれません）。
どうすれば　インストールできるでしょうか？ご教授お願いします。

Comment: 「pygameがインストールできません。」とのことですが、他のモジュールはインストールできているのでしょうか？　「〇〇〇のところが漢字で、それが原因かなとおもうのですが、それをアルファベットに変更する方法もわかりません」とありますが、漢字の箇所はユーザー名ですよね？対応としては新しくアルファベットから成るユーザーを作成することになるかと思います。

Comment: まあ`venv`で別の場所(パス名に全角文字や空白を含まないフォルダ)に仮想環境を作ってそこで作業すれば良いのでは？ [venv --- 仮想環境の作成](https://docs.python.org/ja/3/library/venv.html) 大掛かりなことをする前に試してみれば全角文字が原因なのか直ぐにわかるでしょう。

Comment: ご返答ありがとうございます。   　merinoさん：漢字の個所はユーザー名だと思います。そこはPCを起動したときに選択するアカウント名だと思ってたのですが、違うみたいで、PCを起動したときに選択するアカウント名をアルファベットに変えてみたのですが、色々なファイルのプロパティの場所を見てみてもユーザー名は以前と変わらずですし、新しく作ったファイルのプロパティの場所もユーザー名は以前と変わってはいませんでした。　　　ユーザー名を変えるにはどうしたらいいでしょうか？また、ユーザー名をかえると、今までのファイルはみな使えなくなってしまうのでしょうか？　　　kunifさん：venv --- 仮想環境の作成」というところをクリックして一通り読んでみました。仮想環境というのはいったいどんなものなんでしょうか？また当方が使用しているPythonはPython311なのですが、それでも使えるのでしょうか？　　　　質問ばかりで申し訳ありません。実はまだプログラミングを学び始めて１か月たっていない（正確には1980年代のBASICにはさわっています）初心者なので、知らないことばかりで困っております。

Comment: merinoさんの言うユーザー作成は例えばこちらの方法です。[\[Windows 10\] ユーザーアカウントを追加する方法を教えてください。](https://www.fmworld.net/cs/azbyclub/qanavi/jsp/qacontents.jsp?PID=1810-7976) ただし可能ならば後々の事を考えるとOSを再インストールし、その際にこちらの方法 [Windows 10Homeのインストール時にローカルアカウントを作成する方法](https://4thsight.xyz/36917) でローカルアカウントで作成した後、Microsoftアカウントでのログインに切り替える方が良いでしょう。仮想環境を使う場合の例はこちらです。[venvによる仮想環境作成](https://www.python.ambitious-engineer.com/archives/1623) あと、PythonはBASICからすると非常に癖のある言語ですので、いきなりpygameを使おうとするよりはPythonの基礎から学ぶコース的なものを一通り学習することをお勧めします。

Comment: ご返答ありがとうございます。　　kunifさん　OSの再インストールとか大掛かりなことになってますが、再インストールをすると、今使っているアプリとかショートカットとかはつかえなくなってしまう感じがするのですが、どうなのでしょうか？私としてはいまの環境はこのまま使っていきたいのですが無理なのでしょうか？

Comment: 今のまま使う場合は、今後も全角文字のユーザー名(フォルダ名)が原因のトラブルが何度も発生する可能性が高いですね。それらトラブルの発生を仕方ないものとしてその都度対処するつもりがあるなら出来るでしょう。ただし先にコメントしたように全角・空白を含まない作業用のフォルダをvenvで作ればトラブルは軽減されるはずです。OSの再インストールする場合はアプリケーションも再インストールすることになるので、その時に自動時あるいはオプション指定によってショートカットは作られるはずです。インストール時にそういうオプションを見かけたら指定するように心掛ければ良いでしょう。

Comment: ご返答ありがとうございます。　　仮想環境とはどんなものなのか実際に見てみないことには・・・よく見もしないのに作ってしまうと、とんでもないことになりそうで怖いです。色々考えましたが、もう少しコンピューターのことを勉強した方がいいのかなと思いました。コンピューターの基礎的な部分を学んでから再度挑戦してみようと思います。　多数のご助言ありがたかったです。　merinoさん、kunifさん、code-onigiriさん　どうもありがとうございました。

Answer (score 0):

pythonをC:ドライブにインストールしたら、できるかもしれません
まずインストールするときに
下のcustomを選び(PATHも忘れずに押して)
Nextを選び
そこで全てのユーザーにインストールするか、C:ドライブ
のような場所にインストールすればいいと思います